# Separating Web Api and Web Site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

i'm new to asp.net web api, owin, and everything related to it.
I'm trying to find the best way to do this scenario:

1 - Web api to have all the connections and rest service

2 - Web site to show data to user on a browser using the restful service

3 - An mobile app that have some functionalities like the web site and access the restful service to get all the information

My doubt is: what's the best practice related to the login? I'll use owin/oath2 with Identity to login, but since it's going to be implemented on the web api, the login/register/forgot password should be on the web api directly (like the project template does) or should i move most of the functionality to the web site? Of course its easier to leave in the web api, but if i do it, i must duplicate my razor templates just to call the login part. Can someone give me a path to follow?

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, so your Web Api project has razor templates?

Comment: that's what i'm saying, if i use the project template, there will be templates. that's the point i'm trying to avoid. In my web api stays only what should be there, but i'm not sure how should i do the entire login part separating the web api from the views on my web site (of course i could use restsharp for example, but i not sure if i will be not losing most of the identity power doing so)

Answer (score 0):

the answer is not, your web api should not have any html or js or css file, only the services that your need, the web api exposes the functions to register the user, next when you have to do request, you must Send a token, you can obtain the token using the URL that you have configure in owin, the URL is like /token and Send the username and pass.

Regards,

Comment: Yeah, that's what i'm trying to achieve. But if i do all my calls using the /token directly, how can i use the "remember me" feature from the SignInManager? (isPersistent = true)

Comment: Well, it depend, you can login the user in your web mvc, and next get the token to call the services, other option is use the remember credentials of the web browser